# Please undelete my question wrongly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion

[How can a seller know the buyer's believing a product to feature something, but not the buyer's believing that the seller contracted this feature?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15534/89)

appears wrongly deleted, as this question differs from and so does not duplicate:

[How is it realistic that a buyer would fail to communicate some feature of a product needed by the buyer, to a seller?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15231/89).

Answer (score 3):

I undeleted that question, so anyone so inclined can vote to reopen it.

I, however, am not personally inclined to cast that vote at present.  There is something about that question that *seems* inappropriate to this Stack Exchange (and probably any general Stack Exchange).  I'm not sure I can explain exactly why right now, but here are things going through my head as I consider this: Yes, that question is amenable to a proper third-party answer.  *But* if the author you are quoting does not provide the answer then the question could just as easily have been introduced by careless writing ... in which case [the only "correct" answer can be provided by the author](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/458/10).  The fact that you found something confusing in a book about law doesn't mean it's a good question about law.  This isn't "Law Book Club."

Particularly in this case: You link to the author's web page, where his email address is featured prominently!  Why not ask the question of him?

Comment: I will try your suggestion from your last paragrpah.