# How can I correct a wrongful closure, if the Meta post is unilaterally deleted?

Tags: discussion

Initially, [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15534/89) was closed by 1 user and 1 moderator, by reason of being a duplicate. So I posted [in Meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/570/89) to clarify the distinction and so wrongness of the duplication, but it was also unilaterally deleted.

So I post here to check how I can correct the closure.

Answer (score 6):

Meta is not for questioning every routine action that occurs on the site.  That is why *I* deleted your *second* Meta question regarding the closure and deletion of what appeared to be [a duplicate question on the main site](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15534/10).

NB: The closure of your main-site question as a duplicate was not "unilateral:"  It was the result of votes by *two* users.

Again, nothing here requires more meta discussion than occurred on [your first meta question on this](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/550/please-undelete-my-question-wrongly-marked-as-duplicate).

To be fair, the standard process for reopening requires votes from either a moderator or from *five* 3000+rep users.  Since presently there are only a dozen of those on this site *I* will reopen the question if other active users request it in comments to [my first meta answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/551/10).

Comment: I received VTC/VTR privilege when I hit 500 here, so it may be worth pointing out that betas have lower requirement. I believe I also flagged for closure as duplicate and/or voted to leave closed.

Comment: @Nij Yes, this is true - [69 users can vote to close or reopen](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/363/alltime/law). Privilege changes are tied to site design changes, so roughly when that happens the reputation requirements will be raised.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I would have done the same thing. Your question appears to be a duplicate, and I will not reopen it as it stands.

Many, many questions on this site have been closed as off-topic, yet most users make them more suitable for the site by editing. Very few of them appeal to meta where they feel it was closed incorrectly, and in very few cases would I overturn the vote to close.

In your case, these questions are duplicates, if not in wording, then in spirit. If you can edit the subsequent question to distinguish it more obviously from the original, then perhaps we can consider re-opening the question.

Since the opportunity arises, perhaps you should reflect on why so very few of your questions have a positive score.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I honestly do not understand how anyone can fail to see the difference between the two questions: can you please explain why you judge them duplicates?

Comment: One is asking how realistic b is, the other is asking why c is not more realistic than b? That's what I gather, and in this case, even if the questions are not duplicates in wording, they are duplicates on the basis that the answers to the questions would be similar or identical.