# Why are questions from law books off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I had some questions now deleted, and that I can't see anymore, that were clearly legal, but spring from law books. I remember some snarky unwelcoming comment that this site isn't a law book club.

But why can't we ask legal questions from law books that aren't the law (not judgments or statute)? [This question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83/25327) raises legal theory

> Answering legal theory type questions, e.g. "why does the US constitution prohibit ________" (which is usually a complicated question).

Weren't my questions about the theory of contract law? Thanks! Have a good weekend!

Comment: "Why does the Constitution prohibit [thing?]?" is a question about political and sociological motivation, and has nothing to do with the law. "**How** does the Constitution prohibit [thing]?" would likely be on-topic, if it was not either a direct statement (if that thing is a state establishment of religion, the question is directly answered by *just actually **reading*** the Constitution...) or too broad to be answered here. I'm not sure how that's relevant to whether a question comes from a law textbook or a different source, or what your deleted questions even were, so I'm VTC Unclear.

Comment: For context: This user's questions can be seen publicly [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/25327/chrome?tab=questions&sort=newest).  Previous relevant questions [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456/10) and [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/550/10).  (And I apologize if my answer there seemed unwelcoming; the question was posed by a more experienced user who had participated in other discussions on this subject.)

Comment: @Nij Legislative Intent IS ON TOPIC - https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/17474.

Answer (score 3):

### They aren’t off topic for being from law books

However, a question may be off-topic for all sorts of reasons irrespective of its source.